# How come sometimes the Find window will not close?

Tags: texshop

I am running TeXShop 2.47 on a PPC Mac with OS 10.5.8.

When I want to search for something in my document I press command-F and a small window opens that says Find on top. As usual there is a red button on the upper left to close this window, yet sometimes when I press that nothing happens. I can't seem to tell what circumstances cause this.

It can be annoying when I have multiple windows open, especially because it automatically overlaps the Viewer. What can I do to make the Find window close when this happens?